# Handling large String values in database VARCHAR2 columns

Tags: oracle11g, varchar2

I have defined an `VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)` field in the database. Often, we run into issues where the client input is more than 2000 characters and we end up missing out on the record. I am not sure if setting the field(s) to maximum characters would be the best way to solve this.

What would be the best way to handle such arbitrary large text input ?

Comment: I think you may find [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/is-there-any-point-in-undersizing-varchar-columns) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [CLOB (Character Large Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_sqltypes.htm#BABEFDEF) column. These can store up to 4gb of character data.

Answer (score 1):

CLOB. It's slower, can't be a primary key, some other limitations apply; but it can hold up to 4Gb.

Comment: Hopefully, @darkie is not trying to make varchar2(4000) as primary key. If he does, he will face lot of performance issues when the data will grow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident the client input will never exceed 4000 characters then you can increase the field size to that. Otherwise, you'll need to use a [CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_sqltypes.htm#BABEFDEF).